# BindingSource update issue

Tags: c#

Using BindingSource, I was able to send valid data from the Categories form to the Create Category form as follows. There is no problem when adding a new record. However, there is no change in updating the current record. Probably because I have given the DataRow type as DataSource. But I couldn't find any other solution. Why is it not updating? I request your help in this matter.
Thanks.

```
//Create Category form
public partial class FrmCategoryOLUSTUR : Form
    {
        public bool Status = false;
        public QuestionDbDataSet.CategoriesRow Valid;
}

private void FrmCategoryCreate_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into table 'questionDbDataSet.Categories'. You can move or remove it as needed.
            this.categoriesTableAdapter.Fill(this.questionDbDataSet.Categories);

            //If the state variable is True, it will be edited.
            if (Status == true)
            {
                this.Text = "Edit Category";
                CategoriesBindingSource.DataSource = Valid;
            }
            else
                CategoriesBindingSource.AddNew();

        }

private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               CategoriesBindingSource.EndEdit();
categoriesTableAdapter.Update(questionDbDataSet.Categories);
                    }

// Categories form where categories are listed
private void FrmCategories_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into table 'questionDbDataSet.Categories'. You can move or remove it as needed.
            this.categoriesTableAdapter.Fill(this.questionDbDataSet.Categories);
            ListCategories.DataSource = questionDbDataSet.Categories.ToList();
            ListCategories.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
        }

QuestionDbDataSet.CategoriesRow Valid=null;
        private void ListCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Current = (QuestionDbDataSet.CategoriesRow)ListCategories.SelectedItem;
            Current = Current;
                  }

private void BtnCategoryEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Edit FrmCategoryOLUSTUR = new FrmCategoryOLUSTUR();
            Edit.Status = true;
            Edit.Valid = Valid;
            Edit.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: Probably because you didnt implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) so your binding source doesnt know, when it has been updated. 

Afaik, if your variable `Valid` is of type [`ObserveableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0) you dont need to, because it uses it implicit.

Comment: Hi
So how should I update the code? I am giving a different DataRow object as DataSource with if condition. Could it be related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the package Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView using Nuget Package Manager. I got the result I wanted by using this package ready-made.
I advise.

Comment: It’s worth noting that this project hasn’t been updated in eight years, and has been archived by its owner ([source](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView)).

Answer (score 0):

I no longer work with form apps. Form applications are outdated. I use WPF instead. Data binding processes are used more effectively in WPF projects.